# While installing magento I am getting an error : Parse error

Tags: php, magento, netbeans, wamp

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in G:\wamp\www\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php on line 93

My php version is 5.5.12 and i want to update this to 5.6. so, that this error will go away. Does anybody have any idea about this updation process and how to do it ?

Comment: What version of WAMPServer are you currently running

Comment: Sir, WAMPSERVER 2.5  :)

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are using WAMPServer2.5, I would suggest upgrading to WAMPServer3.0.3.

The upgrade will upgrade WAMPServer2.5 to WAMPServer3 directly, without loss of anything you are using in WAMPServer2.5

Once you get to WAMPServer3.0.3 you can then install the update to WAMPServer3.0.8 and be totally up to date, without loosing any data.

[WAMPServer3.0.3 32bit Download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%203/WampServer%203.0.0/Updates/wampserver2.5_x86_update_3.0.3.exe/download)

[WAMPServer3.0.3 64bit Download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%203/WampServer%203.0.0/Updates/wampserver2.5_x64_update_3.0.3.exe/download)

Then upgrade WAMPServer to its latest version 3.0.9 at time of writing.
[WAMPServer3.0.9](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/)

Note: If you are using 32bit then use the 32bit upgrade, and if you are using 64bit use the 64bit upgrade. Dont try and upgrade from 32bi to 64bit.

Once that is installed upgrade to WAMPServer3.0.8 directly using [WAMPServer3.0.8 upgrade](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%203/WampServer%203.0.0/Updates/wampserver3_x86_x64_update3.0.8.exe/download)

You should still have all your old versions of MySQL/PHP/Apache but now there will be newer versions available for you to switch to as well, including a version of PHP5.6 and PHP7.0

**Always make sure you have a current backup of all your code and databases before doing any upgrade! JUST IN CASE !!**